# How to show Admob in SurfaceView

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview

I try to show Admob on my SurfaceView.

1. I use framework from book beginning android games from Mario Zechner
2. In framework there is a class (AndroidFastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable) and in that class there is line canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null); where framebuffer is Bitmap where is all drawn in game.
3. In that framework there is a class (AndroidGame extends Activity) where is line setContentView(renderView);

Here renderView is AndroidFastRenderView that is SurfaceView, Now I try to add Admob but I don't no how.

I can create Admob like this

AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MyID");

but where to add that view

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob's [Ad Catalog](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/src/com/google/ad/catalog/layouts/OpenGLViewExample.java?repo=ad-catalog-android) sample application has an example similar to this.  In the above example, the `AdView` was defined in XML.  But at a high level, you'll probably want something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <AdView ...
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <AndroidFastRenderView ...
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where the `AdView` sits at the top or bottom outside of the AndroidFastRenderView.  If you're doing it in code, I'd suggest you create a `RelativeLayout`, add the `AdView` as a subView of the `RelativeLayout` at the bottom (for example), and then add the `renderView` as a subView of the `RelativeLayout`, but above the `AdView`.