# Admob on Runnable SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, surfaceview, runnable

How can I create my admob banner in the below codes? I completed a sweet game but now I am stuck in advertizing stuffs now :(. The admob's official instructions are not talking about *SurfaceView*.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {      
FastRenderView ren;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    try {
        ren = new FastRenderView(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ren.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(ren);       

class FastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
...
```

Comment: My answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159247/android-admob-without-xml?answertab=votes#tab-top

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At last it is solved :).